# Almost orthogonality of independent random vectors

Tags: pr.probability, measure-concentration

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent isotropic random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$,
then $\mathbb{E}\|X_i\|_{2}^{2}=n$, $\mathbb{E}\langle X_1,X_2\rangle^{2}=n$.

How can I show from the above result that in high dimensional spaces, independent and isotropic random vectors are almost orthogonal?

Comment: see the answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995623/why-are-randomly-drawn-vectors-nearly-perpendicular-in-high-dimensions